# jQuery draggable and droppable clone events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have elements where you can drag droppable (cloned) items. However when I drag parent items to left side, droppable/draggable is not working on clones. Is it possible to get event bindings copied to clones too? Or how can I bind events to these clones? See jsfiddle for example.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {

    $(".draggable").draggable({ 
        helper: 'clone',
        greedy: true
    });
    $(".droppable").droppable({
        greedy: true,
        hoverClass: "data-hover",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone());
            $(".draggable").draggable({ helper: 'clone' });
        }
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L9xYK/